# Disable specific WooCommerce payment method for all subcategories of a given top category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to deactivate PayPal for all subcategories by a given category slug for WooCommerce. Currently my following code just deactivates the payment method for one category. Is it possible to deactivate for all subcategories?

```
<?php
/**
 * Disable payment gateway based on category.
 */
function ace_disable_payment_gateway_category( $gateways ) {
    // Categories that'll disable the payment gateway 
    $category_slugs = array( 'tobacco' );
    $category_ids = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'slug' => $category_slugs, 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

    // Check each cart item for given category
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        $product = $item['data'];

        if ( $product && array_intersect( $category_ids, $product->get_category_ids() ) ) {
            unset( $gateways['ppec_paypal'] );
            break;
        }
    }

    return $gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'ace_disable_payment_gateway_category' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others with the same issue. @LoicTheAztec code was extended by a code part to check if the single product site is a part of the category too:

```
 * Disable payment gateway based on category.
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'disable_payment_gateway_subcategory' );
function disable_payment_gateway_subcategory( $payment_gateways ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return $payment_gateways; // Not on admin

    $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
    $term_slug    = 'tobacco'; // Main top category
    $term_id      = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy )->term_id; // get term Id
    $children_ids = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy ); // Get all children terms Ids
    array_unshift( $children_ids, $term_id ); // Adding main term Id to the array

    // Check on single product site 
    $cateID = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'ids') );
    if ( array_intersect( $children_ids, $cateID ) ) {
        unset($payment_gateways['ppec_paypal']);
    }

    // Check each cart item for given subcategories of a top category
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $term_ids = wp_get_post_terms( $cart_item['product_id'], $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'ids') );

        if ( array_intersect( $children_ids, $term_ids ) ) {
            unset($payment_gateways['ppec_paypal']);
            break; // stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $payment_gateways;
        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2**

To disable specific payment gateway for a subcategory of a top product category, use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'disable_payment_gateway_subcategory' );
function disable_payment_gateway_subcategory( $payment_gateways ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return $payment_gateways; // Not on admin

    $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
    $term_slug    = 'tobacco'; // Main top category
    $term_id      = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy )->term_id; // get term Id
    $children_ids = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy ); // Get all children terms Ids
    array_unshift( $children_ids, $term_id ); // Adding main term Id to the array

    // Check each cart item for given subcategories of a top category
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $term_ids = wp_get_post_terms( $cart_item['product_id'], $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'ids') );

        if ( array_intersect( $children_ids, $term_ids ) ) {
            unset($payment_gateways['ppec_paypal']);
            break; // stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $payment_gateways;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Same with replacing payment method to 'bacs'.

Comment: And I guess this would just work for the checkout or cart? This should be disabled on the single product page too. The express PayPal checkout is activated on the single product page too. Sorry, I don't want steal your time, but I'm not as familiar as you in PHP, normally I'm a Java developer. Maybe you can save my day :)

Comment: Dude!!! It works perfectly now. Thank you so so much! I will accept the answer. But one more question: if I add an item of 'tobacco' and go to checkout, my server log outputs a '408' errorcode without any further information - it comes from your code. Any ideas? Nevertheless thank you for your time!

Comment: @OzzyB. I don't catch… You mean if you add an item that has "tobbaco" as category, you get an error? I ave just updated the code to include "tobacco" term Id to the array of terms Ids…

Comment: With the code (the code before too) there are some troubles with WooCommerce. I can't open the WooCommerce Dashboard and Customers. All other without problems.

This is the output of the server: https://i.ibb.co/B2n6tB6/Unbenannt.png

Comment: And this is how my functions.php looks like: https://i.ibb.co/7vhsBkd/Unbenannt.png

Comment: I've doublechecked now. It is only working if a tobacco product is already in the cart. Otherwise it doesn't work properly.